# Is Kong last of its kind?

Tags: kong-skull-island, monsterverse

**Spoiler ahead:**

We get to know that Kongs family or maybe entire species is wiped out by the skull creatures. We saw their bones in skull creatures' territory. Only Kong the king left. Now skull creatures are a lot in numbers. But we just saw Kong himself. So is Kong alone? If so then in future, when Kong dies no one to protect from those creatures!! Cause Kong alone can't reproduce.

Is there any official explanation? What is the lifespan of Kong?

Comment: Kong may be the last, but Kong movies will be made forever.

Comment: According to his __[Twitter account](https://twitter.com/kongskullisland/status/837784671840681984)__ he indeed is the last of his kind ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'official' explanation, but in the world of the film, the character Marlow (John C. Reilly) explicitly states that Kong is the last of his family.

Of course, that's just, like, his opinion.  There might be more that he's not aware of. Maybe Kong has an estranged younger brother that went off to find his fortune.

And, of course, there might be other families on other islands.  The characters in the film wouldn't know about those, either.

Comment: Even if a female of the species is alive somewhere, the Kongs are still under the minimum viable population as far as we can tell.  Here's hoping the Hollow Earth has a chance for Kong to avoid extinction :)